# How to extract conditional statements from linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to be able to extract conditional statements from following query inside a function. It's a linq to EF query. How should i do that? is there any alternative way so that object oriented principles be applied (like open/closed)?

```
    var query = new UvwRequestAssignmentManagementBO().GetAll().Where(uvw => (uvw.FK_ProcessStep == 2)
        && (uvw.FK_Entity == SecurityContext.Current.User.FK_Entity)
       && (uvw.FK_Manager == 15))
       .Select(p => new ReqSupAdminGridVm()
                {
                    NameFamily = p.NameFamily,
                    RequestDate = p.RequestDate,
                    RequestNo = p.RequestNo,
                    RequestType = p.RequestType == 1 ?"a"
                                          : (p.RequestType == 2 ? "b"
                                          : (p.RequestType == 3 ? "c" :
                                          (p.RequestType == 4 ? "d" : ""))),
                    RequestEvaluationStatus = p.RequestEvaluationStatus_Aggregation == 1 ? "a"
                                          : (p.RequestEvaluationStatus_Aggregation == 2 ? "b"
                                          : (p.RequestEvaluationStatus_Aggregation == 3 ?"c" 
                                          :(p.RequestEvaluationStatus_Aggregation == 4 ? "d" : ""))), 
                });
```

For Example instead of writing :

```
    RequestType = p.RequestType == 1 ?"a"
                                          : (p.RequestType == 2 ? "b"
                                          : (p.RequestType == 3 ? "c" :
                                          (p.RequestType == 4 ? "d" : ""))),
```

i want to be able to write this inside another class :

```
RequestType = ReqType.GetReqType(p.RequestType);

string GetReqType(int type){

           switch(type){
                      case 1:
                       return "a";
                      case 2:
                       return "b";
                          }
}
```

Comment: "Extract" as in remove, reuse, reflect at runtime, or something else?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Could you please explain a bit more? Do you want to write your own functions such as GetAll, Where, etc the way Linq exposes?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Extract as in reuse

Comment: @Imran i wrote an example. i don't want to have conditional statements inside linq query.

Comment: It looks like you want to fetch all the data from the data base and then filter it. I would not recommend if it is the case. Server side filtering results in far less data to be transferred on wire than transferring all the data over the wire and filtering it at the client side.

Comment: If you have R#, it's a one (or two, at most) step automated refactoring

Comment: @sehe R# won't do anything because its an Expression.

Comment: @Imran NO, I want to return an Iqueryable.

Comment: @1AmirJalali Could you edit the tags further to make it clear which Linq provider you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), it lets you do what I think you are asking, I used it myself in a recent project and the code is reusable as well as readable.

I create predicates like this for my models:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace MyModels
{
    using Predicate = Expression<Func<Component, bool>>;

    public partial class Component
    {
        public static Predicate HasKeywordContaining(string keyword)
        {
            return c => c.Keywords.Any(k => k.Value.Contains(keyword));
        }

        public static Predicate IsOwnedBy(string ownerName)
        {
            return c => c.OwnerName.Contains(ownerName);
        }

        public static Predicate HasPartNoContaining(string partNo)
        {
            return c => c.PartNo.Contains(partNo);
        }
    }
}
```

I can then use these to construct queries like this:

```
var whereComponent = PredicateBuilder.True<Component>();

whereComponent = whereComponent.And(Component.HasKeywordContaining(keyword));
whereComponent = whereComponent.And(Component.IsOwnedBy(ownerName));

var components = from c in db.Components.Where(whereComponent)
```

And of course this involves no client side filtering.

Comment: I need and Iquerable<T> and the important part for me is returning a string like the GetTypeReq function but in this case it doesn't work because it's a linq to EF predicate witll work just fine but i need string not bool

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method in a separate class, like this:

```
public static class ReqTypeExtension
{
    public static string GetReqType(this int reqType)
    {
        switch (reqType)
        {
            case 1:
                return "a";
            case 2:
                return "b";
            case 3:
                return "c";
            case 4:
                return "d";
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
RequestType = p.RequestType.GetReqType()
```

If you are set on this syntax:

```
RequestType = ReqType.GetReqType(p.RequestType);
```

Declare a static method on the ReqType class, like this:

```
public class ReqType {

    public static string GetReqType(int reqType)
    {
        switch (reqType)
        {
            case 1:
                return "a";
            case 2:
                return "b";
            case 3:
                return "c";
            case 4:
                return "d";
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    var query = new UvwRequestAssignmentManagementBO().GetAll().Where(uvw => (uvw.FK_ProcessStep == 2)
        && (uvw.FK_Entity == 1)
        && (uvw.FK_Manager == 15))
        .Select(p => new ReqSupAdminGridVm
        {
            NameFamily = p.NameFamily,
            RequestDate = p.RequestDate,
            RequestNo = p.RequestNo,
            RequestType = GetReqType(p.RequestType),
            RequestEvaluationStatus = GetReqEvalStatus(p.RequestEvaluationStatus_Aggregation),
        });
```

if you add the following local helper functions:

```
private static string GetReqEvalStatus(int agg)
{
    switch (agg)
    {
        case 1: return "a";
        case 2: return "b";
        case 3: return "c";
        case 4: return "d";
        default: return "";
    }
}

private static string GetReqType(int type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case 1: return "a";
        case 2: return "b";
        case 3: return "c";
        case 4: return "d";
        default: return "";
    }
}
```

See it working [**Live on IdeOne**](http://ideone.com/lBiDxD)

If you want, you can move the helper functions into another class/file (http://ideone.com/EsK6W8):

```
            RequestType = ReqType.GetReqType(p.RequestType),
            RequestEvaluationStatus = ReqEvalStatus.GetReqEvalStatus(p.RequestEvaluationStatus_Aggregation),
```

And in separate file(s):

```
static internal class ReqEvalStatus
{
    public static string GetReqEvalStatus(int agg)
    {
        switch (agg)
        {
            case 1: return "a";
            case 2: return "b";
            case 3: return "c";
            case 4: return "d";
            default: return "";
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
static internal class ReqType
{
    public static string GetReqType(int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1: return "a";
            case 2: return "b";
            case 3: return "c";
            case 4: return "d";
            default: return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I need to return an Iqueryable<T>.The query represented here is a linq to EF. GetAll here just returns and Iqueryable<T>

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I missed that requirement in the question